# jQuery load causes body to turn white

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm simply transitioning from a welcome page to a new page with content via jQuery's `fadeOut/fadeIn` and `load` functionality.  Both pages have the same CSS and frameworks loaded, and both have black backgrounds. However, when it loads the second page, the background changes to white.

This is not a 'white flash' like the other questions asked on here. Literally, the body turns to white and stays that way. Any ideas why or what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure I've overlooked something very basic.

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function(){
            $('#go').click(function() {
                $('html').fadeOut(2500, function() {
                    $(this).load('second.html', function() {
                        $(this).fadeIn(2500);
                    });
                });
                return false;
            });
        })
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <a id="go">Go!</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

**second.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>&nbsp;</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**:

```
body {
  background: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the problem clear? You are hiding the `html` element, create a wrapper element and hide that instead.

Comment: Wow. Facepalm. Please take away all my badges.

Comment: `$(function(){` is shorthand of `$(document).ready(function() {`, so, remove anyone from these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

analysis...

```
$('#go').click(function() { // clicking go...
      $('html').fadeOut(2500, function() { // html fade out....
           $(this).load('second.html', function() { // html content changes...
                $(this).fadeIn(2500); // this line can't run... cause entire html changes... including the <head> that has the script... this line is goodbye...
           });
      });
      return false;
});
```

suggestion, only change the content of `<body>` tag...